# using ngif inside the loop and toggling the table row with specific class when clicking on table row with another class in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a table generated from the data and there are 2 **tr** with class **default and toggle-row** when i click on **tr with class default** it should only toggle the corresponding **tr with class toggle-row** however my code toggles all the toggle-row class when clicked on any one of table row with class default. how do if fix this. i am using ***ngIF** to toggle the table rows.

**Template file** is like this

```
<table class="table table-container table-responsive" id = "team-members">
        <thead class="table-heading">
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="data-item" *ngFor = "let member of teamMember; let i = index" >
            <tr id ="{{i}}" (click)="Toggle(i)" class="default">
                <td *ngFor = "let hrs of member.Value.hoursLogged">
                    {{ hrs }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <ng-container *ngFor = "let subtask of member.Value.subTasks">
                <tr class="toggle-row" *ngIf="toggle" > 
                        <td>
                            {{ subtask.taskType }}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngFor="let hrs of subtask.subtaskHoursLogged">
                            {{ hrs }}
                        </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-container>
        <tbody>
</table>
```

basically this loop creates the structure

```
 <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="1" class="default"><tr>
            <tr class="toggle-row"></tr>
            <tr class="toggle-row"></tr>
            <tr class="toggle-row"></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="2" class="default"><tr>
            <tr class="toggle-row"></tr>
            <tr class="toggle-row"></tr>
            <tr class="toggle-row"></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="3" class="default"><tr>
            <tr class="toggle-row"></tr>
            <tr class="toggle-row"></tr>
            <tr class="toggle-row"></tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

and i want to toggle table-row class when clicked on default class only inside that tbody

and **typescript** file for this template is like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataServiceService } from "../../services/data-service.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.css']
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {
  private teamMember: any[];
    public toggle = false;
  constructor(private dataserve: DataServiceService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
     this.dataserve.getTeamMemberData()
      .subscribe(
          (data: any) => {
                        var localarray= [];
                        for (let key in data){
              localarray.push({key:key, Value:data[key]});
            }
                        this.teamMember = localarray;
                        console.log(this.teamMember);
                    }
            );
  }
  Toggle(value){
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to move **toggle** variable inside **member.Value.subTasks** variable to make things work for each row.

As **toggle** is global variable, it will simply update the view for all rows.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor = "let subtask of member.Value.subTasks">
            <tr class="toggle-row" *ngIf="subtask.toggle" > 
                    <td>
                        {{ subtask.taskType }}
                    </td>
                    <td *ngFor="let hrs of subtask.subtaskHoursLogged">
                        {{ hrs }}
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
```

you need to change **Toggle(i)** function to update the **member.Value.subTasks** variable.

Hope it helps!.

Comment: basically when **tr with id 1** is clicked i want to toggle **tr with toggle-row class** only with in that tbody , but as u mentioned i have toggle property assigned to every tr with toggle row class it simply removes all the rows with class toggle-row, i have edited the question and added the typescript file for this template can u please look at it once